# Infinite Scrolling/Pagination on backbone.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to use the [Pagination plugin](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator) for backbone.js to create an infinite scroll feature like in Twitter, where clicking the button/link `#pagination a` will load the next page of results from the backend and append it to the current view `PhotoListView`.

**Problem:** I am trying to follow the plugin's examples [here](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone.paginator/examples/netflix-infinite-paging/index.html) and source [here](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator/tree/master/examples/netflix-infinite-paging). So far, I manage to get the JSON data `data` from the backend on clicking the link `#pagination a`.

How do I make use of the model-view binding of backbone.js to append new views `photoListItemView` to the view `photoListView` when the button `#pagination a` in the view `PaginationView` is clicked?

I thought that when `this.collection.requestNextPage()` of method `appendRender` in `paginationView` is called, the newly retrieved models will be added to the collection `photoCollection` which will trigger `photoListView`'s `this.collection.bind('change', this.render, this);` event trigger, causing the newly retrieved models to be appended?

**Views**

```
PhotoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#photo_list',

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('change', this.render, this);
        this.collection.bind('add', function() {
            console.log('added to collection');
        }, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        //$(this.el).html('');
        this.collection.each(function(photo, index) {
            if(index % 7 < 3) {
                $(this.el).append(new PhotoListItemView({ model: photo }).render().el);
            } else {
                $(this.el).append(new PhotoListQuadItemView({ model: photo }).render().el);
            }
            console.log('render');
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

PhotoListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagNAme: 'div',
    className: 'photo_box',

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_PhotoListItemView').html() ),

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.close, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
            console.log('render item');
        return this;
    },

    close: function() {
        this.unbind();
        this.remove();
    }
});

PhotoListQuadItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagNAme: 'div',
    className: 'photo_box',

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_PhotoListQuadItemView').html() ),

    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.close, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    },

    close: function() {
        this.unbind();
        this.remove();
    }
});

PaginationView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#pagination'),

    events: {
        'click #pagination a': 'appendRender'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_pagination').html() ),

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html( this.template() );
    },

    appendRender: function() {
        this.collection.requestNextPage()
            .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // HOW DO I APPEND THE NEW DATA VIEWS?
        });
    }
});
```

**Collection**

```
PhotoCollection = Backbone.Paginator.requestPager.extend({
    model: Photo,

    paginator_core: {
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://www.domain.com/explore/all?'
        },

    paginator_ui: {
        firstPage: 1,
        currentPage: 1,
        perPage: 7,
        totalPages: 10
    },

    server_api: {
        '$page': function() { return this.currentPage; }
    },

    parse: function (response) {
        return response;
    }

});
```

**Router**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'explore'
    },

    initialize: function() {

    },

    explore: function() {
        console.log('explore!');
        this.photoList = new PhotoCollection();
        this.paginationView = new PaginationView({ collection: this.photoList });
        var self = this;
        this.photoList.fetch({
            success: function() {
                self.photoListView = new PhotoListView({ collection: self.photoList });
                self.photoListView.render();

            }
        });
    }

});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: right now how does your PhotoListView know that PaginationView is clicked? you need to bind the event to view so that when ever collection is fetched bind your view to reset event ad the view is rendered automatically

Comment: @Kishore I binded it to the reset event instead of change event, and now it working good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kishore has said. Binded to the `reset` event and it works now.